# How to disable a specific profile in pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

My USB microphone is recognized also as a speaker (both analog and digital). Is there a way to blacklist/disable this output "feature", leaving the input feature active?

This is the relevant entry of the mic in `pacmd list-cards`:

```
        name: <alsa_card.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Meteor_Mic-00>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 22
        properties:
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "Samson Meteor Mic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Samson Technologies Samson Meteor Mic at usb-0000:02:00.0-4.4.1, full speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:4.4.1:1.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4.1/1-4.4.1:1.0/sound/card2"
                udev.id = "usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Meteor_Mic-00"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "17a0"
                device.vendor.name = "Samson Technologies Corp."
                device.product.id = "0310"
                device.product.name = "Meteor condenser microphone"
                device.serial = "Samson_Technologies_Samson_Meteor_Mic"
                device.form_factor = "microphone"
                device.string = "2"
                device.description = "Meteor condenser microphone"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone-usb"
        profiles:
                input:analog-stereo: Ingresso «Stereo analogico» (priority 65, available: unknown)
                input:iec958-stereo: Ingresso «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» (priority 55, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo: Uscita «Stereo analogico» (priority 6500, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Duplex stereo analogico (priority 6565, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Uscita «Stereo analogico» + Ingresso «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» (priority 6555, available: unknown)
                output:iec958-stereo: Uscita «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» (priority 5500, available: unknown)
                output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Uscita «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» + Ingresso «Stereo analogico» (priority 5565, available: unknown)
                output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Duplex stereo digitale (IEC958) (priority 5555, available: unknown)
                off: Spento (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Meteor_Mic-00.iec958-stereo/#1: Meteor condenser microphone Stereo digitale (IEC958)
        sources:
                alsa_output.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Meteor_Mic-00.iec958-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Meteor condenser microphone Stereo digitale (IEC958)
                alsa_input.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Meteor_Mic-00.analog-stereo/#2: Meteor condenser microphone Stereo analogico
        ports:
                analog-input-mic: Microfono (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                iec958-stereo-input: Ingresso digitale (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                
                analog-output-speaker: Altoparlanti (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                iec958-stereo-output: Uscita digitale (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
```

In short, I would like to keep all the input profiles:

```
input:analog-stereo: Ingresso «Stereo analogico» (priority 65, available: unknown)
input:iec958-stereo: Ingresso «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» (priority 55, available: unknown)
```

and remove the output profiles:

```
output:analog-stereo: Uscita «Stereo analogico» (priority 6500, available: unknown)
output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Duplex stereo analogico (priority 6565, available: unknown)
output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Uscita «Stereo analogico» + Ingresso «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» (priority 6555, available: unknown)
output:iec958-stereo: Uscita «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» (priority 5500, available: unknown)
output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Uscita «Stereo digitale (IEC958)» + Ingresso «Stereo analogico» (priority 5565, available: unknown)
output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Duplex stereo digitale (IEC958) (priority 5555, available: unknown)
```

Comment: Hello Roberto, I was about to post an answer until I read that you have a microphone which is also detected as a speaker. I posted my answer to my question I was researching here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1364580/40581 The problem here seems to be that the configuration that ships with Ubuntu (or stock PulseAudio) auto generates all kinds of possible profiles and among them profiles which don't make much sense. I have had some experience with similar PulseAudio related things in the past. Let me know if my answer solves your main issue, or if we need to create a custom configuration.

Comment: The members of the PulseAudio mailing lists may also be able to help you I you haven asked them already. In your case that may be the best option, so that the microphone is properly detected on all PulseAudio installations in future releases.